# .htaccess, rewrite part of url for specific domain

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite a part of an url for a given domain like:

`www.example.com/.*` -> `www.example.com/sub/.*`

i.e rewriting `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/sub` while keeping the rest of the path.

I have tried many approaches for several hours and this is the one most promising so far, however still unsuccessful:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^www.example.com/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/sub/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas what is wrong with the one above or other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/sub%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The pattern which comes after `RewriteRule` syntax matches the Request URI not HTTP HOST. So for example `www.example.com/hello` the part `hello` will be used in pattern to be match.

```
#Start with hello do your stuff
RewriteRule ^hello target_url [Flags]
```